# Flutter Session - Get resaults by user session

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart

I have flutter app where user input data and that data is stored on mysql.
Everything works perfect on my PHP, HTML on web. But in flutter I can't get session of user.

```
    Future getData() async {
var url = 'https://azer.maverus.ba/api/read.php';
var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
return json.decode(response.body);
```

}
I have that script and it read only data that I type inside flutter. And can't read data from database from curent user.

Comment: This doesn't have any key named session.

Comment: What do you mean? How to add key named session?

Comment: What are you actually trying to get?

Comment: So, now in my flutter aplication, I'm getin all data from /read.php, I wan't only data that user who loged in posted. It works on my web when I log in. But in flutter doesn't.

Comment: are you passing the session key in the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `header` to pass `Authorization` key to the `API` check the code below

```
  Future getData() async {
    var url = 'https://azer.maverus.ba/api/read.php';
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url),headers: <String, String>{
      "Authorization" : "YOUR KEY HERE"
    });
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
```

Comment: I think this is solution, I don't have much experience with this. But what I need to put in string, string and what is my key?

Comment: how are you performing this on your website can you explain?

Comment: public function getInvoiceList(){
     $korisnik = $_SESSION['email'];
  $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->invoiceOrderTable." WHERE author = '$korisnik'";
  return  $this->getData($sqlQuery);
 }

Comment: So I have that part of code to list invoice by session. I share same database for login and for data on website and fluter.

Comment: In PHP  for mysql you are using session but when you created this API how do you filtering user in this API?

Comment: public function checkLoggedIn(){
  if(!$_SESSION['userid']) {
   header("Location:https://azer.maverus.ba/index.php");
  }
 }

Comment: Do you send any auth key in response after  log in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240390/discussion-between-azer-and-diwyansh).